# RxJava How to create a non blocking Single from CompletableFuture<Long>

Tags: rx-java2

given a repository class, which returns a single:

```
Single<SomeObject> find()
```

and a CompletableFuture which returns a Float:

```
CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture
```

I would like to invoke the repository method first and based on the result, I need to invoke the completableFuture. This is the code I have:

```
repository.find()
          .flatMap(s -> {
              CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture = serviceReturningCompletableFuture;

              return Single.fromFuture(completableFuture);

          }).subscribe(System.out::println)
```

Problem here is that `Single.fromFuture` will block and therefor can not be used.

In order to work around this I tried things like:

```
repository.find()
          .map(s -> {
              CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

              return Flowable.fromFuture(completableFuture);
          }).subscribe(System.out::println)
```

while this works fine without blocking, the subscribe function prints the following instead of the number which is returned by the CompletableFuture

```
io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromFuture@62ce978e
```

I also tried to use the non blocking converter to single from `net.javacrumbs.future-converter:future-converter-rxjava-java8:1.2.0`:

```
repository.find()
          .map(s -> {
              CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

              return toSingle(completableFuture);
          }).subscribe(System.out::println)
```

but, this leads to pretty much the same output: `net.javacrumbs.futureconverter.rxjavacommon.RxJavaFutureUtils$ValueSourceBackedSingle@3f1eebb8`

What am I missing?

Comment: There is a library to bridge to Java 8 constructs: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaJdk8Interop#completionstage-to-rxjava

Comment: thanks for your comment and this library :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some fiddling later and this helper method:

```
public static <T> Single<T> toSingle(CompletableFuture<T> future) {
    return Single.create(subscriber ->
            future.whenComplete((result, error) -> {
                if (error != null) {
                    subscriber.onError(error);
                } else {
                    subscriber.onSuccess(result);
                }
            }));
}
```

seems to do the trick:

```
repository.find()
          .flatMap(s -> {
              CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture = serviceReturningCompletableFuture;

              return toSingle(completableFuture);

          }).subscribe(System.out::println)
```

and as @akarnokd pointed out in the comment, there is this lib:
https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaJdk8Interop#completionstage-to-rxjava which works pretty much the same way:

```
repository.find()
          .flatMap(s -> {
              CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture = serviceReturningCompletableFuture;

              return SingleInterop.fromFuture(completableFuture);

          }).subscribe(System.out::println)
```